# Attributes not inherited via tkinter.button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing the number of step-by-step participants within the framework of the classical one. In normal code in def move function I try to reset attributes from one button to unexpected but when I use get_info I get nothing. I've been sitting for 5 hours, I can not figure out how to fix it.
I tried to remake all classes into 1, but even after that it didn't inherit the attributes I needed.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import threading


class Color(object):
    EMPTY = 0
    BLACK = 1
    WHITE = 2


class Move:
    xstart = -1
    ystart = 0
    xdest = 0
    ydest = 0


class Button(tk.Button, object):
    IMG = None
    PlayStatus = None
    Getstatus = 0
    MovementPointsStart = 0
    MovementPoints = 0
    Heatl = 0

    def __init__(self, color, master, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        self.color = color
        super(Button, self).__init__(master, width=6, height=3, *args, **kwargs)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Юнит {self.x} {self.y} {self.PlayStatus}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Юнит {self.x} {self.y} {self.PlayStatus}'

    def nextturn(self):
        if self.MovementPointsStart > self.MovementPoints:
            print(self.MovementPointsStart)
            self.MovementPoints = self.MovementPointsStart
            print('sosnul')
        else:
            pass

    def get_info(self, Button, x, y):
        info = 0
        if self.color == Color.BLACK:
            info = (type(self), self.PlayStatus, self.MovementPointsStart, str('/'), self.MovementPoints, 'Black')
        else:
            info = (type(self), self.PlayStatus, self.MovementPointsStart, str('/'), self.MovementPoints,'White')
        return info

    def get_moves(self, Button, turn):
        print(turn)
        i = 1
        while i==1:
            print('zestko')
            if turn % 2 == 0 and self.color == Color.WHITE:
                print('sosnul')
                if self.MovementPoints > 0:
                    print('huiza')
                    if Button.get_color(Move.xstart, Move.ystart) == Color.WHITE or Button.get_color(Move.xdest, Move.ydest) == Color.EMPTY:
                        if Move.xdest < Move.xstart:
                            xend = Move.xstart - Move.xdest
                        else:
                            xend = Move.xdest - Move.xstart
                        if Move.ydest < Move.ystart:
                            yend = Move.ystart - Move.ydest
                        else:
                            yend = Move.ydest - Move.ystart
                        self.MovementPoints = self.MovementPoints - (xend + yend)
                        break
                    break
                else:
                    print("У вас нет очков перемещения")
                    break
            else:
                if turn % 2 == 0:
                    print("Сейчас не ваш ход")

            if turn % 2 == 1 and self.color == Color.BLACK:
                print('sosnul')
                if self.MovementPoints > 0:
                    print('huiza')
                    if Button.get_color(Move.xstart, Move.ystart) == Color.BLACK or Button.get_color(Move.xdest, Move.ydest) == Color.EMPTY:
                        if Move.xdest < Move.xstart:
                            xend = Move.xstart - Move.xdest
                        else:
                            xend = Move.xdest - Move.xstart
                        if Move.ydest < Move.ystart:
                            yend = Move.ystart - Move.ydest
                        else:
                            yend = Move.ydest - Move.ystart
                        self.MovementPoints = self.MovementPoints - (xend + yend)
                    break
                else:
                    print("У вас нет очков перемещения")
                    break
            else:
                print("Сейчас не ваш ход")
                break

class Game:
    turn = 0
    ROW = 10
    COLUMNS = 10
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.title('Eve Offline')
    win.geometry("900x560")
    x=0
    y=0

    def __init__(self):
        self.Button = []
        for x in range(Game.ROW):
            temp = []
            for y in range(Game.COLUMNS):
                btn = Button(Color.EMPTY, Game.win, bg='green', x=x, y=y, text='bebra')
                temp.append(btn)
            self.Button.append(temp)


    def set_Button(self):
        self.Button[1][2] = Button(Color.BLACK, Game.win, x=1, y=2,  text='Suck')
        self.Button[1][2].PlayStatus = 1
        for x in range (Game.ROW):
            for y in range (Game.COLUMNS):
                self.Button[x][y].config(command=lambda button=self.Button[x][y]: self.get_click(button))

    def create_window(self):
        for x in range(Game.ROW):
            for y in range(Game.COLUMNS):
                btn = self.Button[x][y]
                btn.grid(row=x, column=y)
        Muvprikaz = tk.Button(bg='green', width=20, height=4, text='MOVE', activebackground='blue')
        Muvprikaz.config(command=lambda button=self.Muvprikaz: self.Muvprikaz())
        Muvprikaz.place(x=550, y=300)
        NextturnB = tk.Button(bg='gray', width=20, height=4, text='Next Turn')
        NextturnB.config(command=lambda button=self.nextturn(Game.turn): self.nextturn(button))
        NextturnB.place(x=700, y=300)

    def start(self):
        self.set_Button()
        self.create_window()
        self.print_button()
        self.win.mainloop()

    def print_button(self):
        for row_btn in self.Button:
            print(row_btn)

    def get_color(self, x, y):
        return self.Button[y][x].color

    def get_info(self, x, y):
        return self.Button[y][x].get_info(self, x, y)

    def move(self):
        print(Move.xdest, Move.ydest)
        print('sukablat')
        print([Move.xdest],[Move.ydest])
        self.Button[Move.xdest][Move.ydest].config(background='gray', text='SS')
        self.Button[Move.xdest][Move.ydest].config(command=lambda button=self.Button[Move.xdest][Move.ydest]: self.get_click(button))
        self.Button[Move.xdest][Move.ydest] = self.Button[Move.xdest][Move.ydest]
        self.Button[Move.xstart][Move.ystart] = Button(Color.EMPTY, Game.win, bg='green', x=Move.xstart, y=Move.ystart, text='bebra')
        for x in range (Game.ROW):
            for y in range (Game.COLUMNS):
                self.Button[x][y].config(command=lambda button=self.Button[x][y]: self.get_click(button))
        self.create_window()
        self.Button[Move.xstart][Move.ystart].Getstatus = 0
        print('blatsuka')

        self.Button[Move.xstart][Move.ystart].config(bg='green', text='bebra')
        self.Update()

    def nextturn(self, turn):
        self.turn +=1
        print(self.turn)
        for x in range(Game.ROW):
            for y in range(Game.COLUMNS):
                if self.Button[x][y] == self.Button[x][y]:
                    self.Button[x][y].nextturn()
        print("hui")
        return turn

    def get_click(self, clicked_button):
        if Button.Getstatus == 0:
            print(Button.Getstatus)
            x = (clicked_button.x)
            y = (clicked_button.y)
            Button.Getstatus = Button.Getstatus+1
            clicked_button.config(bg='red')
            self.print_button()
            print(self.get_info(x, y))
            print(Button.Getstatus)
            Move.xstart = x
            Move.ystart = y
            Button.Getstatus == 0
        elif Button.Getstatus == 1:
            Button.Getstatus = 0
            print(Button.Getstatus)
            clicked_button.config(bg='green')

    def dest_click(self, clicked_button):
        x = (clicked_button.x)
        y = (clicked_button.y)
        clicked_button.config(bg='blue')
        Move.xdest = x
        Move.ydest = y
        print(Move.ydest, Move.xdest)
        print('eblan')
        self.Move()

    def Move(self):
        self.Button[Move.xstart][Move.ystart].get_moves(self, self.turn)
        self.move()

    def Muvprikaz(self):
        if Move.xstart>-1:
            self.print_button()
            print(Move.xstart, Move.ystart)
            for x in range (Game.ROW):
                for y in range (Game.COLUMNS):
                    self.Button[x][y].config(command=lambda button=self.Button[x][y]: self.dest_click(button))
        else:
            pass

    def Update(self):
        for x in range (Game.ROW):
            for y in range (Game.COLUMNS):
                self.Button[x][y].config(command=lambda button=self.Button[x][y]: self.get_click(button))
        Move.xstart = -1
        Move.ystart = 0
        Move.xdest = 0
        Move.ydest = 0



g = 1
game = Game()
game.start()
```

Comment: I poked the buttons a little and found out that the attributes on the chain occur if you "go" along the same diagonal, but then I don't understand anything, it doesn't work.

Comment: The classical one of what? What is this program supposed to do, and what is it doing wrong?

Comment: the program should draw a graphical interface at startup, when you click on any cell, it takes the coordinates of this cell and saves them, then after pressing the move button, it should change the button functions, then when you click on any cell again, it should change the objects of start and end coordinates. everything except the last action is just executed, but for some reason the objects are not replaced. I don't speak English very well, so I can't explain clearly.

Comment: All that should be in the question.